# Run a mocha test with multiple js files and generate separate JSON reports

Tags: json, node.js, windows, mocha.js, chakram

I have several mocha & chakram test case files, located on current directory:

```
test1.js
test2.js
test3.js
..and so on
```

I want to run a mocha test sequentially and generate a JSON reports for every test case.

**What I want**

```
Test1.json (result of test1.js)
Test2.json (result of test2.js)
Test3.json (result of test3.js)
..and so on
```

**What I have tried**

1. Create a batch file which contains:

   ```
    mocha test1.js --reporter json > Test1.json
    mocha test2.js --reporter json > Test2.json
    mocha test3.js --reporter json > Test3.json
   ```

   When I run it, it runs only the first line
2. Modified the batch file to be only one line

   `mocha test1.js --reporter json > Test1.json test2.js --reporter json >
   Test2.json test3.js --reporter json > Test3.json`

   This generates only one file 'Test3'.json. or

   `mocha "./testfolder/*.js" --reporter json > Test.json`

   This generates only one file.
3. Using mocha --recursive

   ```
    mocha --recursive *.js --reporter > test1.json
   ```

   It goes to all subfolders. Even if this works, it will only generate one file. Reorganizing the folders is probably not an option.
4. I have tried using mochawesome too.However, in this case, I want JSON file as the result / reporter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding ```--exit``` to each line in your first soluton?

Comment: @KorbinianKuhn I added it and mocha still runs only the first line.

Answer (score 1):

```
mocha -R json test/main.js 2>&1 | tee ./selenium-results/selenium-results.json
```

This works for me. the `./selenium-results/selenium-results.json` is where you would define your file path.